# Linear Algebra, Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis

An odd function of period 2$\pi$ is appoximated by a Fourier Series with N terms. The appoximate error as measured by mean-square deviation is

$$E_N =\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi\left( f(x) - \sum_{n=1}^N b_n \sin nx \right)^2 dx$$

By differentiating $E_N$ with respect to the coefficients $b_n$, find the values of $b_n$ that minimize $E_N$.

The main problem for me was I didn't know how to differentiate this function. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have the definition of the coefficients $\,b_n\,$ ? These are functions of $\,x\,$ ...

Comment: How can I differentiate with respect to funtion?

Comment: $$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx\,dx \ldots$$ But perhps I see a problem here (unless you were given something different): the coefficients $\,b_n\,$ are *not actually* just functions of $\,x\,$ but in fact just numbers and thus their derivative is zero...

Comment: I know this but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Well, if the derivative is zero then you **already** know their derivative, don't you? :)

Comment: I think the meaning of the question is the following: the coefficients $\,b_n\,$ *themselves* are the variables! So now we can derivative wrt them...Give it a try.

Comment: I tried but failed, as I said while I ask this question. Please help DonAntonio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea only: putting $\,b:=(b_1,b_2,...,b_N)\,$ and regarding the given function as a real one on $\,\Bbb R^N\,$ :

$$\frac{d}{db}(E_N)=\frac{d}{db}\left[\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \left(f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^N b_n\sin nx\right)^2dx\right]=\sum_{k=1}^N\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d}{db_k}\left(f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n\sin nx\right)^2dx$$

Assuming differentiation under the integral sign is allowed (Leibnitz theorem)